# Рекурсия вызова метода API, python 3.5

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия

Коллеги, добрый день. Прошу помощи в написании оптимального алгоритма для рекурсивного вызова API.

Суть такова - есть метод API (**getProductType**), который позволяет получить остаток товаров разного типа (**productType**):

```
"stats": [   
    { "label": "Окна", "segment": "productType==Окна", "count": 11, },  
    { "label": "Двери", "segment": "productType==Двери", "count": 22, },  
    { "label": "Плинтуса", "segment": "productType==Плинтуса", "count":33 },  
    { "label": "Шторы", "segment": "productType==Шторы", "count": 44, }  
   ]
```

А так же есть методы, которые позволяют получить остатки товара в разрезе:

1. цвета - **productColors** ( метод **getColors**),
2. состояния -**productCondition** (новый или БУ) (метод **getCondition**),
3. текстуры
4. и т.д.

Каждый метод апи имеет входной параметр (необязательный) - **filter**. Он позволяет отфильтровать значения, которые соответствуют заданному выражению. Причем он может принимать несколько выражений одновременно, все они будут объединены логическим "И", т.е. например чтобы получить остаток товаров в разрезе **"цвет"**, для которых тип товара - **"Двери"** и состояние - **"Новый"**, можно вызвать такой метод : `getColors(filter="productType==Двери;productCondition==Новый")`

При получении статистики, в каждом словаре мы имеем ключ **segment** , который как раз-таки может быть использован во входном параметре (**filter**) любого из доступных методов API.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы на выходе получить таблицу со вложенностью, которая может быть динамической (большое кол-во разных методов API), например посмотреть срез "Тип товара -> Цвет -> Состояние" (productType -> productColour -> productCondition) :

```
  "stats": [   
    { "label": "Окна", "segment": "productType==Окна", "count": 11,      
        "getColors": [
            {"label": "Зеленый", "segment": "productColour==Зеленый", "count": 11,
                "getCondition": [
                 { "label": "Новый", "segment": "productCondition==Новый", "count": 22, },  
                 { "label": "БУ", "segment": "productCondition==БУ", "count":33 },  
                ]
            },
            { "label": "Красный", "segment": "productColour==Красный", "count": 11,
                "getCondition": [
                 { "label": "Новый", "segment": "productCondition==Новый", "count": 22, },  
                 { "label": "БУ", "segment": "productCondition==БУ", "count":33 },  
                ]
            }
        ]
    },  
    { "label": "Двери", "segment": "productType==Двери", "count": 22, 
        "getColors": [
            {"label": "Рыжий", "segment": "productColour==Рыжий", "count": 11,
                "getCondition": [
                 { "label": "Новый", "segment": "productCondition==Новый", "count": 22, },  
                 { "label": "БУ", "segment": "productCondition==БУ", "count":33 },  
                ]
            }
        ]
    },      
    { "label": "Плинтуса", "segment": "productType==Плинтуса", "count":33, ... },  
    { "label": "Шторы", "segment": "productType==Шторы", "count": 44, ... }  ,
    ...
   ]
```

Т.е. по сути нужно получить сначала данные по первому уровню (Тип товара), затем в первом объекте из статистики выдрать ключ "segment" , и вызвать второй метод с входным параметром filter, содержащим этот ключ. Затем, для полученной статистики проделать тоже самое, чтобы получить третий уровень, использовав при этом filter="*segment из 1 уровня*;*segment из второго уровня*", и так по рекурсии.

Буду благодарен любой подсказке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
methods = {
    'productType':      [getProductType, 'getProductType'],
    'productColour':    [getColors, 'getColors'],
    'productCondition': [getCondition, 'getCondition']
}

def getStat(stat):
    # stat = 'productType;productColour;productCondition'

    def getResult(lvl = 0, statValues = []):
        if lvl == len(statList):
            return []

        method = methods[statList[lvl]][0]
        filter = ''.join(statValues)
        data = method(filter)

        for item in data:
            seg = item['segment']
            del item['segment']
            result = getResult(lvl + 1, statValues[:] + [seg])
            if result:
                item[ methods [ statList[lvl + 1] ][1] ] = result
        return data        

    statList = stat.split(';')    # превращаем в список ['productType', ...]
    result = getResult()    # запускаем рекурсию
    return {'stats': result}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: А может подскажете заодно, как можно в этой же функции удалять параметр "segment"? чтобы в конечном словаре в элементах не было этого ключа.

Comment: Подправил, смотрите по коду.

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как с вами можно связаться? Хотел обсудить пару вопросов.

Comment: Не уверен, что здесь можно оставлять свои контакты. Отпишу подробней завтра.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/a2XYNXvtePoeAg